# Selecting value of input

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a problem with selecting some values of input. Its's sometimes working but sometimes not working but its only on IOS device. Here is my example:

```
<input onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);" value="3401000140" readonly="true">
```

when click on the input tooltip must be appear. But its sometimes appear but sometimes no ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the exact length.

`<input onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0,this.value.length)" value="3401000140" readonly/>`